# Save User Session on Redis, Game matching system

Tags: node.js, rest, unity-game-engine, redis

I am developing a matching system for my game. The aim is to match 5 players from country A and 5 players from country B. My current design is to create a queue for each country and push users' ids when they click start matching button. Then each time a new user start matching. I will have the server iterating all the queues to find the 5vs5 pattern. If found, the server will pop these users out and establish a match among them.

The current problem is how should I store these data? I can either store each queue in redis (the key can be the country id and value can be the queue). But I am afraid if there will be any racing issue since the the data will be updated rapidly. Or I can just create a variable (nodejs server) on the sever to hold all the data.

I am also wondering how League of Legend or Counter Strike establish their matching systems (Not about the balancing user's level part, but establishing connection)